# How do I append the same row to each element of a 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab

> > a = ones(2,2,2)

a(:,:,1) =

```
 1     1
 1     1
```

a(:,:,2) =

```
 1     1
 1     1
```

I want to append ones(1,1) to the bottom row of each of a(:,:,1) and a(:,:,2)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do with [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function:

```
 a = cat(1, a, ones(1,2,2));
```

or [VERTCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html):

```
a = vertcat(a, ones(1,2,2));
```